# Is there a way to add an argument to class __init__ method with monkey patching?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

If there's a class

```
Class A:
    def __init__(arg1, kwarg1=...):
        ...something happens here with args and kwargs
```

is there a way to add another argument by monkey patching this class? How to keep everything that happens in it's `__init__` in place, without repeating it anywhere?

Comment: Why do you need to monkey-patch init specifically? Could you just add the new attribute directly to the instance?

Comment: You might want to separate certain behaviors such as logging into a separate part of the program, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked:

```
from package import module

class ChangedInitClass(module.SomeClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1, another_arg, kwarg1=...):
        super().__init__(arg1, kwarg1=kwarg1)
        # does something with another_arg

module.SomeClass = ChangedInitClass
```

Comment: That is basically my answer below.

Comment: @Alex G Rice: the question is about monkey patching, your answer is not, I can't use inheritance alone because I can't touch classes that inherit from the one I'm patching etc etc

Comment: I see- sorry I misunderstood the question. Glad you got it solved through a combination of inheritance and monkey patch.

Answer (score 2):

It affects also classes that are subclasses of A:

```
old_init = A.__init__

def new_init(self, foo, *args, *kwargs):
    old_init(self, *args, *kwargs)
    self.foo = foo

A.__init__ = new_init
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do the same thing by subclassing, and no need to monkey patch. You could add new positional args, or just throw more items into kwargs. Something like this:

```
Class A:
    """same class A as before"""
    def __init__(self, arg1, kwarg1=...):
        ...something happens here with args and kwargs

Class B(A):
    def __init__(self, another_arg, arg, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(self, arg, **kwargs)
        # B does something with another_arg here
```